# 2006 Camry Remote Control Programming doesn't save for more than a day

Tags: toyota, camry, fob

I tried to program my 2006 camry remote controls. After completing the programming, it will stay for a day and remotes doesn't work again. Any idea what's wrong? I have brand new batteries in remotes (so, thats not the issue). Toyota dealer said 79.99 for diagnosing and extra to fix or reprogram.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 3):

I found the following instructions here: http://freeremoteinstructions.com/toyota/toyota-camry-2002-2006/

1. Start with the key out of the ignition, drivers door is open all others closed and drivers door is unlocked.
2. Perform these steps within 5 seconds.
   A. Insert the key into the ignition(Do NOT Turn) Pull key out.
   B. Insert the key into the ignition(Do NOT Turn) Pull key out.
3. Perform these steps within 40 seconds.
   A. Close then open the drivers door.
   B. Close then open the drivers door.
   C. Insert the key into the ignition(Do NOT Turn) Pull key out.
4. Perform these steps within 40 seconds.
   A. Close then open the drivers door.
   B. Close then open the drivers door.
   C. Insert the key into ignition and leave it in ignition.
   D. Close the drivers door.
   E. Turn the ignition to ON (Do NOT Start) then back to OFF.
   F. Remove the key from the ignition.
5. Within 3 seconds, the power door locks should lock then unlock automatically
   indicating successful entry into programming mode.
   Return to step 1 if the locks do not cycle at this point.
6. Perform these steps within 40 seconds.
   A. Press the lock and unlock buttons on the remote simultaneously for 1.5 seconds.
   B. Immediately after letting go of the lock and unlock buttons,
   Press the lock button by itself and hold for 2 seconds. Within 3 seconds, the door locks should lock and then unlock once indicating successful programming. If the door locks cycle twice, repeat steps A and B in step 6 as the remote was
   not accepted.
   C. Repeat steps A and B in step 6 for each new remote.
7. Open drivers door.

I hope that works for you!